# Google Sheets ImportXML Split Definitions

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, filter, import, google-sheets-formula

I made a [Google Sheets Dictionary](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1naAq32VzfmqGmggKzzOuVjekhcW3vmArEKvPgENQenA/template/preview) for my ESL students. My issue is when the sheet is pulling multiple definitions. I would like it to only pull the first/top definition from the site. I know there is a way to fix this but can't seem to figure it out.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IMPORTXML("https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/"&A4,"//span[@class='def_text']")),":",FALSE,TRUE),1,1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/"&A4,
 "//ul[@class='o_list verdana_font']")
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/"&A4,
 "//span[@class='def_text']")
```

[image]

or if you want just first one try:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/"&A4,
 "//span[@class='def_text']"), 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added an "answer" with images to clarify my issue.

Comment: @JamesOlson answer updated